# Rsync fails to sync flags

Tags: macos, mac, rsync

I am trying to sync two folders along their extended attributes, however some files are always synced every single time without any apparent reason.

Debugging rsync I found out that the remote file flags value is different from the one I have locally:

```
[sender] i=34166 /Volumes/MyDisk Documents/local/ mode=040755 len=204 uid=501 gid=20 flags=0
[receiver] i=34166 2 Documents/local/ mode=040755 len=204 gid=20 flags=88
```

I tried deleting the remote folder and sync the whole thing again, but I always get problems where some files/folders are constantly recognized as modified.

What is included in the flags field? I have tried comparing the attributes and ACL of both folders with "ls -lO@ae" and they look the same.

Answer (score 0):

In 90% of the cases I use rsync with the following arguments:

```
rsync -vaH --delete from_dir/ to_dir/
```

And the "rm" command as "rm -rvf". But I see that you are using OSX, which has a primitive version of rm, which can't always recursive delete without questions and warnings. I suggest you should google for "gnu fileutils for osx" or same, and install what you found. That rm can.

With rsync doesn't exist this problem, because I has not a primitive version, which the wonderful apple could integrate. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure what was the difference with "flags", but solved this problem by upgrading rsync